# Installing OS on VIDEO hard disks

Tags: hard-drive, installation, video, operating-systems

This is a dumb question since they name these in a confusing way.

I am trying to build an surveillance application in Debian platform.

Since HDD are categorized in [Seagate site](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives) like this:

1. Laptop HDD
2. Desktop HDD
3. SSD
4. ENT.Drives
5. Video Storage

My requirement is for VIDEO DRIVE:: But if I install OS in this video drive :

[Video 2.5 HDD](http://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/video-2-5-hdd/en-gb/docs/video-2-5-hdd-data-sheet-ds1772-1-1212gb.pdf)

Will there be any OS level performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work fine.  The difference between video hard drive and desktop drive is not very much.  The video hard drive is designed to be small, quiet, and lower power.  This is so you will not hear it while you are in the same room and watching TV.  Lower power is also important because the drive will be turned on all the time.

It may not be as fast as a server hard drive, but you will not even notice the difference.

1. Laptop HDD:
   Small physical size for laptops.  Important to be lower power and rugged because laptops can be dropped.
2. Desktop HDD:
   Larger physical size for more storage.
3. SSD:
   Solid State Drive.  Uses electronic storage instead of a magnetic disk.  This is much faster but also costs more.
4. ENT.Drives:
   Enterprise server drive.  Gives more speed than a desktop drive, but less than a SSD drive.
5. Video Storage:
   Designed for DVR use, which needs to be quieter than a desktop drive.

Comment: this should throw me some light.What are all the performance  factor by OS level i should take care.

Answer (score 1):

I would look for reviews with various benchmarks, they are way better than data sheets to measure the performance.

Rotational speed would be the single most important factor performance-wise on these kind of disks. Higher speeds usually bring higher data rates and shorter access times but they may also affect negatively on noise, heat and power consumption.

But, as Kevin stated, "video disks" will be fine for any OS tasks.